# Passing kwargs into a scrapy contract

Tags: python-3.x, scrapy

I am trying to test a scrapy spider using [scrapy contracts](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/contracts.html) and want to know if there is a way to pass in kwargs. The spider takes a `base_url` kwarg to determine where to scrape. The base spider will fail verification if this kwarg is not provided.

The spider:

```
class ChildSpider(BaseSpider):

def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    # Use base url to set start urls
```

The base spider:

```
class BaseSpider(scrapy.Spider):

def __init__(self, base_url=False, **kwargs):
    if not base_url:
        raise ValueError("Base url must be provided")
    self.base_url = base_url.rstrip(" /")
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
```

The contract I added to it's parse() function:

```
"""This is a test.

    @url http://dummy-url.com
    @returns items <min limit>
    @returns requests <min limit>
    @scrapes <attributes>
    """
```

I have been trying to pass a kwarg in with this contract so the verification doesn't fail but have not had any luck. I know I can pass in kwargs using the -a flag for `scrapy crawl`. So far I have tried:

- Appending `-a base_url=<some url>"` to `scrapy check`
- Appending `-a base_url=<some url>"` to `@url` in the contract
- Setting `@cb_kwargs base_url=<some url>` in the  contract